# Converting a grayscale image(which was previously converted from a color image) to color image using PIL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

So, I have written a code that hides data into a grayscale image, and can retrieve back from a grayscale image. I want be able to do this for a color image.
At the moment, I'm thinking to convert a color image to grayscale, hide the data, convert the image back to color. If that's possible.
Another stuff that I'm thinking is, for grayscale, getpixel returns a single value, while for color getpixel returns a tuple, so I also thought of just manipulating only one value of a tuple, (if this is correct).

Edit: Code, where I'm trying to get a value from a tuple of a color image. Also, sorry its not documented at all.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
from helper import tobits

image_list = []

for filename in glob.glob('*.png'):
  image_list.append(filename)
print(image_list)




#onlyforalphas
message = "he23@"*200
#print(message)
messagebi = ''.join(format(ord(x), '07b') for x in message)
#messagebi = tobits(message)
#print(messagebi)

payload = len(messagebi)

print(".........................PAYLOAD LENGTH : ", payload, "..................................................")

width = 512
height = 512

max_a = 0
min_b = 0

max_value = 0
min_value = 10000

z = 0
zi = 0
fileindex = 0
im = Image.open(image_list[0])
#print(im.histogram())
while payload > 0 and z < len(image_list):
  print(".........................PAYLOAD LENGTH : ", payload, "..........................................")
  print("OPENING FILE", image_list[z])
  im = Image.open(image_list[z])
  #print(im.histogram())
  z = z + 1
  hist_list = np.asarray(im.histogram())
  print(im.histogram())
  for i in range(len(hist_list)):
    if hist_list[i] >= max_value:
      max_value = hist_list[i]
      max_a = i
    if hist_list[i] <= min_value:
      min_value = hist_list[i]
      min_b = i
  if payload > max_value:
    print("ERROR:payload size: ", payload, " too large. Trying another image")

  hist_list = np.asarray(im.histogram())    
  print(max_a, " ", max_value)
  print(min_b, " ", min_value)
  payload = payload - max_value
  if payload < 0:
    payload = 0
  hist_list[max_a] = 0
  #zi = 0
  messagelength = len(messagebi)
  #print(messagebi, "   ", messagelength)
  for i in range(width):
      for j in range(height):
          temp = im.getpixel((i,j))[0]
          #print(temp)
          if  temp > max_a and temp < min_b:
              im.putpixel((i,j), temp + 1)
              #print(im.getpixel((i,j)), end = "")
          if zi < messagelength and messagebi[zi] == '1' and temp == max_a:
              im.putpixel((i,j), max_a+1)
              zi = zi + 1
          elif zi < messagelength and messagebi[zi] == '0' and temp == max_a:
              zi = zi + 1
      #print("")
  #imnu = Image.fromarray(hist_list, mode='L')
  print("payload size after ", fileindex, "iteration is:", payload)
  filename = "output/filename" + str(fileindex) + ".png"
  im.save(filename)
  fileindex = fileindex + 1
  print(im.histogram())
```

Comment: Show what have you tried

Comment: @Alderven posted